# Visible text Inaccessible to search bots?

Tags: html, seo

I would like to add some text to my HTML that is *not* accessible or indexed by search bots.

Is it possible to have visible text on a site that is not accessible to search bots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there are a few ways:

#### 1. Deny access with robots.txt (to directories, html pages)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /something.html
```

#### 2. Add robots meta-tag to your html page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

#### 3. Use `<noindex>` tag. Note that it's not supported by all search-robots;

```
<noindex>this may be seen by some of them</noindex>
```

#### 4. Use javascript (to hide just some text and not the whole page).

```
<script>document.write("Something");</script>
```

Comment: Re: 4. Search bots will see the text in the script tag. Whether they choose to extract it or ignore it is ultimately up to the search bot's author. My bot sees that text, as it's part of the HTML DOM which the page fetches.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention about that in your robot.txt file

Hope this will help

http://www.ideaeng.com/tabId/98/itemId/161/5-ways-to-hide-content-from-your-search-engine-an.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Search engines do not execute javascript, so you can inject the text with javascript. Something like this?

```
<span id="text">
<span/>
<script>
    document.getElementById("text").appendChild( document.createTextNode("You can't search me!") );
</script>
```

Or you can do it in Flash, which is another technology that search engines don't including indexing.

If I'm wrong, hope other experts will correct me :)

Comment: Search engines are _starting_ to execute JS. Flash is an option, but it's a rather bad one wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I wrote a bot. With today's JS heavy apps, there is no reason to execute JS. Most of the time, we'd have to rebuild the site using multiple external .js files. A bot crawls 1 file at a time, which is usually the page which renders out the HTML DOM. It doesn't crawl externally linked .js files. However, bots can parse script tags. So we can read what's hidden in them. We may not choose to execute the script tags with eval(), because we're simply looking for links for more pages to crawl. We're not looking to make a client-side calendar component do anything. Hiding text in Flash is a cool idea!

Answer (score 0):

As Prashant mentioned you can use the `robots.txt` file to block access to specific folders or files completely, or you can add a meta tag in your pages so search engines don't index it.  If you just want a specific block of text in your page non-indexable then you can display it via AJAX/JavaScript as that will not be seen by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the users technology & Charlemagne have mentioned some good answers, but here is some more insight on how search bots work:

Good search bots will follow the rules & use meta tags, no index tags, etc... & respect the webmaster's desires to keep content hidden.

Novice search bot authors may write their bots to simply crawl the page & not respect any of the robots.txt rules. Professional bot writers will honor the robots.txt rules, which my search bot does.

Another way is to add it behind a login gate, as search bots usually can't crawl pages where a user has to login to access that content. There is one exception to that rule. Even with a login gate & if the website generates static .html files, the bot can still crawl behind the fence to see content. Using static .html pages is like having a hole in the fence. Pages have to be dynamically generated via a script (.php, .cgi, Node server-side .js files, etc....) when a logged in user's cookie or session variable has been detected.

The reason that search bots don't execute JavaScript, is because search engine bot authors are simply after links & text on the page & they don't want to see JS code in their [search engine results page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_results_page) (SERP). A search bot fetches each page as a string of text. They sees everything that's on that page, which is fetched. The bot then parses the page to extract the page's contents, but it doesn't execute any of the code which is on the page. There is no purpose to the search engine's author to`eval()` the JavaScript code that's found, ***but a search bot certainly sees it!*** The author simply wants to insert text into their database & look for more links. They're not interested in running any client-side processing on that JS code, simply to "find more links". They can already see all of the links on the page & yes, even extract them from `<script>` tags in the JS layer.